# Partially collapsing image on top of the screen in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How to achieve a partially collapsed image in Jetpack Compose? My goal is that when scrolling down a list, the image above the list would start collapsing but it wouldn't fully collapse e.g. stop collapsing after the image size is 50% of the original size.

[Example case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUL4C.png)

This is my solution at the moment. This solution how ever causes the image to fully collapse and I don't know how to stop the collapsing after scrolling x amount.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ExampleAppTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    CollapseImage()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



@Composable
fun CollapseImage() {

    val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()

    val firstItemTranslationY by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            when {
                lazyListState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.isNotEmpty() &&
                lazyListState.firstVisibleItemIndex == 0 -> lazyListState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset * .6f
                else -> 0f
            }
        }
    }

    LazyColumn(state = lazyListState) {

        item {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground),
                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillParentMaxWidth()
                    .graphicsLayer {
                        translationY = firstItemTranslationY
                    }
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                ,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            )
        }
        items(100) { item ->
            Text(text = item.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option I would suggest is putting the image inside a Scaffold. It could look something like this:

```
Scaffold(
    topBar = {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground),
                contentDescription = null,
                .fillParentMaxWidth()
                .graphicsLayer {
                    translationY = firstItemTranslationY
                }
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            )
        }
    }
)
```

For more info take a look at the documentation for Top Bars https://m3.material.io/components/top-app-bar/overview